# Fetch data using where clause on relational model

Tags: mongodb, loopback

In loopback 3.0, I am trying to fetch data from multiple relational models while applying where clause on a relation.

Below is the example JSON for the models:

```
modelA.json
{
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "length": 20
        },
        "modelBid": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        ...
    }
    "relations": {
        "modelB-rel": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "modelB",
            "foreignKey": "modelBid",
            "primaryKey": "id"
        },
        ...
    }
}

modelB.json
{
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": "false",
            "length": "20"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "length": "255"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

SQL equivalent of query which I want to perform:

```
SELECT * FROM modelA a 
LEFT JOIN modelB b
ON a.modelBid = b.id
WHERE b.name = 'abcd'
```

Loopback filter object I am using, which is not providing fetching the intended results:

```
modelA.find({
    include: [
        {
            relation: 'modelB-rel',
            scope: {
                fields: ['id', 'name'],
            },
        }
    ],
    where: {
        modelB-rel: {
            name: 'abcd',
        },
    }
}
...
```

Please help me to correct the filter object to get the same results as of the mentioned SQL equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply filters on related models, you have to put the filter inside the **scope** of the included model. You can use something like this:

```
modelA.find({
    include: [
        {
            relation: 'modelB-rel',
            scope: {
                fields: ['id', 'name'],
                where: {name: 'abcd'}          
            },
        }
    ],
})
```

Comment: This will include all records of modelA and filter only modelB records include inside modelA object which is not equivalent of the mentioned SQL.